# Cube root transformation of income

Tags: regression, modeling, data-transformation

As in the title, I have a question regarding transforming income using cube root.

I want to measure the impact of AA variable (binary) on the income profits from farming of a household. Since income profits can be zero or even negative (in the worse case such as suffering from disease/natural disaster), log transformation seems not work.

Is it ok to transform the dependent variable (in this case, income profits) using cube root? Could you please refer to some papers that have applied the same method?

Or any suggestion to deal with the problem?

Comment: Why did you choose cube root?

Comment: Normally I use log transformation, but in this case, as the income consists of zero and negative value, I think cube root could help, at least it will not drop any observations with zero or negative value.

Comment: Why do you need to transform? To adjust for inflation?

Comment: No. To adjust for inflation, I used the GDP deflator or CPI. 

In fact, I try transforming the income using cube-root to reduce the variation in the dependent variable and to get a better distribution before estimating the impact (similar to what log transformation or square-root transformation functions). The estimation with cube-root income seems better (higher adjusted R2, lower significance level) compare to the model in which income is not transformed. The only problem, I guess is that it might be difficult to interpret the coefficent estimates.

Comment: My model is like Y=a0 + a1D + a2X' + e, in which D is the main variable of interest, and X is a vector of other control variables.

Comment: Schwartz, J. E.  1985. The Utility of the Cube Root of Income. _Journal of Official Statistics_  1(1): 5-19 is one such paper. I owe this reference to Gary Marks. I am not clear that the fit is as good as the author claims.